# what is 'npm un dev' as i accidently run in my terminal?

Tags: javascript, mern

I accidently run a command in my Mern project that ' npm un dev' instead of 'npm run dev' and it delete some packages  and i don't know how to recover these packages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [npm uninstall](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-uninstall):

```
aliases: remove, rm, r, un, unlink
                        __
```

`npm install` should put everything back, assuming package.json wasn't modified.

Answer (score 0):

The list of packages that you deleted is still contained in the package.json file. This file is located in node_modules folder. To fix your issue, just execute the command:

```
npm install
```

or the shorter equivalent:

```
npm i
```

And those packages will be restored.

More details -> https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install

Answer (score 0):

run npm i interminal, this will install all packages which are listed in package.json

Comment: This is not what the op asked. He asked what the `npm un dev` command is.
`npm un` is an alias for `npm uninstall`, so this answer isn't correct